# Função find() da biblioteca set não retorna se achou ou não

Tags: c++, funções, c++11, set

Estou escrevendo um programinha para um exercício da faculdade e estou com dúvida no quesito do `find()`. Eu devo entrar dois números inteiros, verificar se o primeiro número existe dentro do `set` já definido anteriormente. Se existir, eu devo inserir o segundo inteiro no `set`.

Daí eu fiz:

```
cin >> valor >> valord;
if (di.find(valor))
   di.insert(valor);
```

Onde `di` é meu `set` definido já com valores preenchidos.

Está dando o seguinte erro:

> [Error] could not convert 'di.std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::find, std::allocator >((*(const key_type*)(& valor)))' from 'std::set::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator}' to 'bool'

Alguém poderia me explicar se a função `find` retorna `true` ou `false`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta função não retorna um booleano, conforme a [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) retorna um iterador com a posição encontrada, ou a posição após o final se não encontrar nada. Então deveria fazer algo assim:

```
if (di.find(valor) != di.end()) di.insert(valord);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/Find.cpp).

Comment: Muito obrigado !!

Comment: @mahatt veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Existem 2 erros no código.

```
// errado
cin >> valor >> valord;
if (di.find(valor)) // erro de sintaxe: find retorna um "iterator" e não um bool
  di.insert(valor); // erro lógico: deve ser "valord"

// certo
cin >> valor >> valord;
if (di.find(valor) != di.end()) // <----
  di.insert(valord);            // <----
```